# Only last file is executed in the for loop in PHP when passing array of files from android using retrofit

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I am sending an array of images to the server from android. When I try to upload each of them to my database, only the last image is being uploaded. I want each one of the images to be uploaded to my database table as a separate row. Can anyone figure where is the problem for me. Thanks everyone.

here is my php script:

```
  $total = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

for( $i=0 ; $i <= $total ; $i++ ) {

    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['images']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $file_url = $url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;
    $file_path = $path . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $file_path)) {


            $sql = "INSERT INTO posts_media_files (url, post_id) VALUES ('$file_url','$id_bind');";
            $stm = $con1->prepare($sql);

            $stm->execute();

        }

    }


}
```

here is my android code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(new OkHttpClient())
                    .build();

            MultipartBody.Part[] imageArray = new MultipartBody.Part[imagePaths.size()];


            for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.size(); i++) {

                File file = new File(imagePaths.get(i));

                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);


                imageArray[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images", file.getName(), requestBody);
            }

            RequestBody requestEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), userEmail);

            MultipartBody.Part email = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("email", userEmail, requestEmail);

            RetrofitApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadFileMultilPart(imageArray, email);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
        }
```

and here is my retrofit interface:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("post_image.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadFileMultilPart(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] images, @Part MultipartBody.Part email);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your accessing the various `$_FILE` values - although your in a loop, you always refer to the same element...

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
```

you should be referencing each item using your loop variable (`$i`)...

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
```

Do the same with each reference to `$_FILE`.

Comment: I did that before, I did it again, but when I do so, not even one file get's uploaded to the db.

Comment: This may point to the android code not passing the array to your PHP code, is there a way of seeing what is being passed?

Comment: it's just an array of image paths

Comment: can you check my android code to see if there is any problem with it please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my android code:
I must have added this `[]` sign to the name of my array of images, so it should now be,

```
 imageArray[i] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("images[]", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

of course I needed to have also along with this solution followed @Nigel Ren solution.
Thanks @Nigel Ren.